# Swift Table Cell Labels in wrong order

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a table cell set up with two labels. Title and subtitle. The labels are configured using autolayout. Title is pinned with top, left, and right at 20pts (with not constraints). Subtitle is pinned with left, right, and bottom at 20pts (with no constraints).

But when I run the code the subtitle is above the title. If I try to pin the top of the title label to the bottom of the subtitle label with autolayout I get the error "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

How do I place these labels in the proper order?

Thank you!

Comment: try reseting to suggested constraints

Comment: Try removing the bottom pin of the subtitle and instead pin the subtitle top margin to the title label.

Comment: I did as you said Aaron, and after changing the row height everything is good! Thanks!